# Elastich search rollover index with ingest pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have a data stream built out in elastic search through Kibana. I have all the right mappings, index patterns and settings. I created the index that matched the correct index pattern. All good so far.

I have a ingest pipeline that I have created to ensure that any documents that come to ES get a @timestamp field before getting ingested into the index.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_timestamp_pipeline
{
  "description": "Adds a field to a document with the time of ingestion",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I apply the above pipeline to the index as follows

```
PUT /<<index name>>/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "default_pipeline": "my_timestamp_pipeline"
  }
}
```

Everytime I do a manual rollover the ingest pipeline changes get disabled on the index and my documents fail to get indexed due to a missing @timestamp field, which is required as part of a data stream.

Do manual rollovers NOT support ingest pipelines and I have to manually apply the pipeline everytime I do a manual rollover?

I checked that you can pass properties during a manual rollover of an index but not for a rollover of a data stream. Am I missing anything obvious here?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks
Nick

Comment: Are you using an [index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html) to define the mappings and settings of your index / data stream? If not, how do you create your index?

Comment: I use a template.

Comment: Can you please share it?